# PHP Facebook SDK Posting to wall with SDK 4

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Before you all tell me there is already alot of tutorials on how to do this but their isn't any tutorials I foud on the brand new sdk so I am looking for some help.

I have just finished coding my facebook login but every time I login it doesn't ask for permission? And I was wondering how you ask for permission to post to their wall because I want to post on their wall saying they logged in every time they do

```
<?php

// include required files form Facebook SDK

require_once( 'fb/Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookHttpable.php' );
require_once( 'fb/Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookCurl.php' );
require_once( 'fb/Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookCurlHttpClient.php' );

require_once( 'fb/Facebook/Entities/AccessToken.php' );
require_once( 'fb/Facebook/Entities/SignedRequest.php' );

require_once( 'fb/Facebook/FacebookSession.php' );
require_once( 'fb/Facebook/FacebookRedirectLoginHelper.php' );
require_once( 'fb/Facebook/FacebookRequest.php' );
require_once( 'fb/Facebook/FacebookResponse.php' );
require_once( 'fb/Facebook/FacebookSDKException.php' );
require_once( 'fb/Facebook/FacebookRequestException.php' );        
require_once( 'fb/Facebook/FacebookOtherException.php' );
require_once( 'fb/Facebook/FacebookAuthorizationExcetion.php' );
require_once( 'fb/Facebook/GraphObject.php' );
require_once( 'fb/Facebook/GraphSessionInfo.php' );

use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookHttpable;
use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookCurl;
use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookCurlHttpClient;

use Facebook\Entities\AccessToken;
use Facebook\Entities\SignedRequest;

use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\FacebookResponse;
use Facebook\FacebookSDKException;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
use Facebook\FacebookOtherException;
use Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException;
use Facebook\GraphObject;
use Facebook\GraphSessionInfo;

// start session
session_start();

// init app with app id and secret
FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication( '798029503541633','e31a63ad8d46d3c5f4c9aea15af4b163' );

// login helper with redirect_uri
$helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper( 'http://mywebsite.com/fblogin.php' );

// see if a existing session exists
if ( isset( $_SESSION ) && isset( $_SESSION['fb_token'] ) ) {
// create new session from saved access_token
$session = new FacebookSession( $_SESSION['fb_token'] );

// validate the access_token to make sure it's still valid
try {
if ( !$session->validate() ) {
  $session = null;
}
} catch ( Exception $e ) {
// catch any exceptions
$session = null;
}
}  

if ( !isset( $session ) || $session === null ) {
// no session exists

try {
$session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();
} catch( FacebookRequestException $ex ) {
// When Facebook returns an error
// handle this better in production code
print_r( $ex );
} catch( Exception $ex ) {
// When validation fails or other local issues
// handle this better in production code
print_r( $ex );
}

}

// see if we have a session
if ( isset( $session ) ) {

// save the session
$_SESSION['fb_token'] = $session->getToken();
// create a session using saved token or the new one we generated at login
$session = new FacebookSession( $session->getToken() );

// graph api request for user data
$request = new FacebookRequest( $session, 'GET', '/me' );
$response = $request->execute();
// get response
$graphObject = $response->getGraphObject()->asArray();

// print profile data
echo '<pre>' . print_r( $graphObject, 1 ) . '</pre>';

// print logout url using session and redirect_uri (logout.php page should destroy the session)
echo '<a href="http://mywebsite.com/logout">Logout</a>';

} else {
// show login url
echo '<a href="' . $helper->getLoginUrl( array( 'email', 'user_friends' ) ) . '">Login</a>';
}
```

Comment: why all those require_once lines? just use the autoloader as it is documented. for example: http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-php-sdk-4-0-tutorial/ - and of course in the facebook docs.

Comment: btw, what you want to do ("post on their wall saying they logged in every time they do") is not allowed on facebook and counts as spam. just saying. you will definitely not get publish_actions approved for that.